# What is the format of the Docusign recipientId field?

Tags: docusignapi

When using the Docusign API there is a field called `recipientId`.
I am unable to find any documentation explaining the format of the data the API accepts for this field.

One comment suggests its an integer but in practice a Guid string occasionally works.

Does anyone know what data type is acceptable for this field or know of any documentation that details this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the .NET SDK for DocuSign and as in the image below, the `recipientId` is a string. I have assigned Guid anytime I needed to use this field (typically when creating signers).

[image]

The [official documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#certifiedDeliveries) specifies this `recipientId` needs to be unique, hence any Guid will work:

```
recipientId No  String  Unique for the recipient. It is used by the tab element to indicate which recipient is to sign the Document.
```

Answer (score 2):

A RecipientID can be any positive integer or GUID. It must be unique for each recipient on an envelope.