# DocuSign getting a ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS error

Tags: docusignapi

Using the DocuSign C# SDK and when trying to submit an envelope, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS",
  "message": "The specified envelope has duplicate recipients."
}
```

I know this is coming directly from the DocuSign REST API (since the C# SDK just wraps that message back).  According to [this QA](https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00086365) in the DocuSign forum, duplicate recipients (name, email and recipient type) can exist in the same envelope as long as they have a different routing number.  In my case I made sure the routing numbers are different.  However I get the above error message back.

So my question is, if DocuSign API allows for duplicate recipients as long as there is a different routing order, why am I getting this message back?

Comment: `recipientId` must also be unique

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the response. We're using the GUID from our DB associated with the recipient for the recipientId.  Hence a recipient with the same email/name/etc will have the same recipientid.  Is recipientId treated differently in DocuSign?  I assume it was to uniquely id the recipient, not based on the actual route.

Comment: @LosMorales, see [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598409/what-is-the-format-of-the-docusign-recipientid-field/47599866#47599866) about recipientId, it should answer yours.

Comment: The routing order should be enough to differentiate the recipients, are you absolutely positive your routing info is getting sent correctly?  Please post a sample request you are sending so we can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message when using templates that had been set up for user input and no regards to API use.   I found that they'd re-used the field tags both in the data fields as well as when defining recipients, CC's, etc.   When I made these all unique names it cleared up this error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using the same recipientId for many singers.
recipientId of a signer must be unique.