# Error NOTARY_HOSTED_SIGNER_ID_REQUIRED when trying to send an eNotary envelope

Tags: docusignapi, notary

Let my envelope be as below :

```
{
    "allowReassign": "false",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "JVBE",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "PDF",
            "name": "DocumentToNotarize"
        }
    ],
    "emailSubject": "Notary Test",
    "enableWetSign": "false",
    "notification": {
        "expirations": {
            "expireAfter": "4",
            "expireEnabled": "True"
        }
    },
    "recipients": {
        "inPersonSigners": [
            {
                "email": "signer@domain.com",
                "inPersonSigningType": "notary",
                "name": "Signer",
                "notaryHost": {
                    "deliveryMethod": "email",
                    "email": "notary@domain.com",
                    "name": "Notary",
                    "recipientId": "995a0019-f0bc-47bf-94d5-426607388f7b",
                    "tabs": {
                        "notarizeTabs": [
                            {
                                "documentId": "1",
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "xPosition": "100",
                                "yPosition": "100"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "recipientId": "3fa6ffaf-f87e-4f27-9129-6d12d987f59b",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "recipientId": "3fa6ffaf-f87e-4f27-9129-6d12d987f59b",
                            "scaleValue": "0.6",
                            "xPosition": "45",
                            "yPosition": "527"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Which triggers the following error :

```
{
    "errorCode": "NOTARY_HOSTED_SIGNER_ID_REQUIRED",
    "message": "The host signer Id is required to associate with notary in person signer."
}
```

I have found, surprisingly, that if I **only** change the signer's recipientId to an integer as below, it works !?
Am I missing something ? GUIDs are allowed right ?

```
 "recipientId": "3",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "2",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "recipientId": "3",
              "scaleValue": "0.6",
              "xPosition": "45",
              "yPosition": "527"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: GUIDs are allowed, can you triple check that this is the reason? Also, try to completely remove it from the tab only, I'm not sure you have to have it in there. it's already under the recipient object.

Comment: Triple and quadrupled checked and i have the issue when i change the recipientId to a GUID. Also, if I remove it from the tab only, the same error occurs.

Comment: Any chance you can use C# SDK? since I have code that works for this just fine in my blog, I wonder what else I can do to help.

Comment: I'll check if GUIDs are somehow not allowed for NotaryHost cause I used "1" and "2" in my example.

Comment: in my example I didn't have recipientId in there and it's working fine.

Comment: If I remove it from signHereTabs, i get the same error. If I remove it from signHereTabs AND change the GUID to an integer, it works. Can you check if it's a bug on the DocuSign side ? Or if it's a feature and GUIDs are not allowed ? But then again, my DocuSign integration (4 years old now) always used GUID for recipientIds and I've never seen such an issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I have found, surprisingly, that if I only change the signer's recipientId to an integer as below, it works !? Am I missing something ? GUIDs are allowed right ?

If it works when you use an integer, then I recommend you use an integer.

If you want to store a guid with the recipient as metadata that you can later retrieve from the envelope, then use the `customFields` attribute of the `signer` object.

Comment: I can use an integer if needed, but it would be nice to know if DocuSign does not support GUID. It's not clear in the doc as it only mentions that it needs to be unique string (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47600655/7066681)

Answer (score 0):

For most API calls, there isn't a problem to set a GUID for recipientId because most recipient types aren't dependent on another recipient.

The problem here with notary is that the notary and signer recipient are associated by the recipientId and the API logic is designed to parse recipientId as Int, which likely caused the issue. You would also run into the same issue if using in-person signing as it's a very similar process where the host and the in-person signer are a single recipient.

Comment: any official documentation to back this statement ?